# How to horizontally rotate table headings and keep col widths auto?

Tags: html, css, html-table, rotation, css-float

I want to rotate either table headings or an element inside the table headings 270 degrees (using `transform:rotate (270 top left)` or similar), AND have the width of the column be the height (before rotating) of the heading, or fixed to 1em, either would work. I need the table to still behave like a table (i.e., set the widths of cells in subsequent rows).

I've tried every combination of `float`, `table-layout`, `display`, `position`, `width`, and `max-width` that I could think of. I either end up with columns the oriinal width of the rotated text, or rotated labels outside their containing `<th>`. It's driving me insane.

Comment: The answer is that it's impossible. CSS elements rotated 90 degrees keep their "width" as their height, and vice versa. You can't dynamically resize because of that with pure CSS. So you either have to pre-compute the length of the longest element or just use java script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this actually is impossible to do as described (without javascript), but I landed on a good-enough solution by just specifying min/max widths where the min width is as short as my shortest string. So, that's as close as I was able to get:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
transform: rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform-origin: left top 0;
-webkit-transform-origin: left top 0;
transform-origin: left top 0;
max-width: 72px;
min-width: 54px;
height: 36px;
display: block;
text-align: left;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 36px;
background: transparent;
margin-bottom: -24px;
overflow: hidden;
```